# How do i sort a field if I am receiving null at some places in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I am making a firebase query for which this is the output. How do i sort it to (1,2,null,null) order?
I have tried list.sort((a,b)=> a[fieldName].compareTo(b[fieldName])

Comment: Please do not add irrelevant tags to your question. Only add tags that are relevant. I fail to see how this is related to javascript, firebase, firestore, and even flutter in this case. Additionally, code or any logs should be pasted directly into the question(not as images) and be formatted with the tools provided.

Comment: Will keep that in mind thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're looking for a solution in dart, you need to provide a sorting function that handles `null` values, which is something your current solution does not even attempt to do.

The following shows a sorting function that checks if either of the terms are `null` and handles it accordingly. Otherwise, it uses the default `compareTo`.

```dart
list.sort((a,b) {
     if(a == null && b == null) {
       return 0;
     }
     if(a == null) {
       return 1;
     }
     if(b == null) {
       return -1;
     }
     else {
       return a.compareTo(b);
     }
   });
```